# Get value from json data using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am creating a project of Windows Forms Application using C#

I want to show all information(like CityName,CountryCode, etc in different Label) related to IP Address that is on my TextBox.
I already read many article about `JsonConvert` and I don't want to use `JsonConvert`.

here is my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GetIPinfo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<LocaionInfo1> locations = new List<LocaionInfo1>();
            string url = string.Format("http://ipinfo.io/" + txtip.Text);
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string json = client.DownloadString(url);
                LocaionInfo1 location = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<LocaionInfo1>(json);
                locations.Add(location);
            }

            if (locations.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (LocaionInfo1 loc in locations)
                {
                    label9.Text = loc.CityName;
                    label10.Text = loc.CountryCode;
                    label11.Text = loc.CountryName;
                }
            }
        }

        public class LocaionInfo1
        {
            public string IPAddress { get; set; }
            public string CountryName { get; set; }
            public string CountryCode { get; set; }
            public string CityName { get; set; }
            public string RegionName { get; set; }
            public string ZipCode { get; set; }
            public string Latitude { get; set; }
            public string Longitude { get; set; }
            public string TimeZone { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when i Debug this code and Enter IP in my TextBox and then click on Submit Button
My `LocaionInfo1 location = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<LocaionInfo1>(json);`
is `NULL` values.

JSON Data is:

```
{
  "ip": "182.69.151.41",
  "hostname": "abts-north-dynamic-041.151.69.182.airtelbroadband.in",
  "city": null,
  "country": "IN",
  "loc": "20.0000,77.0000",
  "org": "AS24560 Bharti Airtel Ltd., Telemedia Services"
}
```

So please help to get these all values.
I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property names are inconsistent.  For example, in the JSON you have "city" but in your object it is "CityName."  How is the deserializer supposed to know how to map them?

Comment: In order to prevent such inconsistencies I would suggest using something like "http://json2csharp.com". Makes your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

So I can't actually try this because I'm on mobile but for the actual JSON you'd have to add a "/json" to the link

```
string url = string.Format("http://ipinfo.io/" + txtip.Text + "/json");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to help json.net out a bit by giving some mapping by using an attribute on your object properties:

```
    public class LocaionInfo1
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ip")]
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
        ....
    }
```